# How to pass and object from controller to jsp page and then iterate the object to show them in a table?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on Spring MVC project in which I need to pass an object from my Controller to JSP and then I need to iterate that object and show them in a table in jsp page.

Below is my class which holds the data -

```
public class DatacenterMachineMapping {

    private String datacenter;
    private List<MachineMetrics> metrics;

    // getters and setters
}

public class MachineMetrics {

    private String machineName;
    private String t2_95;
    private String t2_99;
    private String syncs;
    private String syncsBehind;
    private String average;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And below is my method in my Controller from which I need to pass an object to JSP and then iterate that object in JSP to show the data in a table -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "testOperation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Map<String, String> testData() {

    final Map<String, String> model = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    MachineMetrics metrics1 = new MachineMetrics();
    metrics1.setAvg("10");
    metrics1.setT2_95("100");
    metrics1.setT2_99("200");
    metrics1.setMachineName("machineA");
    metrics1.setSyncs("100");
    metrics1.setSyncsBehind("1000");

    MachineMetrics metrics2 = new MachineMetrics();
    metrics2.setAvg("20");
    metrics2.setT2_95("200");
    metrics2.setT2_99("300");
    metrics2.setMachineName("machineB");
    metrics2.setSyncs("200");
    metrics2.setSyncsBehind("2000");

    List<MachineMetrics> metrics = new LinkedList<MachineMetrics>();
    metrics.add(metrics1);
    metrics.add(metrics2);

    DatacenterMachineMapping mappings = new DatacenterMachineMapping();
    mappings.setColo("dc1");
    mappings.setMetrics(metrics);

    return model;   
}
```

And below is my JSP page.. And I am not sure how to use the above `mappings` object in such a way in the JSP page so that I can iterate it and show the result in a table -

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Machine Name</th>
                <th>T2_95</th>
                <th>T2_99</th>
                <th>Syncs</th>
                <th>Syncs Behind</th>
                <th>Average</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <!-- what to do here? -->

        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

My data should look like this in the table for `Datacenter 1`-

```
Machine Name    T2_95   T2_99   Syncs   Syncs Behind    Average

machineA        100     200     100     1000            10
machineB        200     300     200     2000            20
```

Do I need to use JSTL for this? Or there are any better approach for this?

Comment: Yes you will need JSTL. That is the best approach.

Comment: @Bart ohh great.. Thanks.. Can you provide an example how would my above example will work if possible with JSTL? I have started working on Spring and JSP recently so still learning..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the JSTL library into your JSP page using

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

This will link the JSTL namespace to `c`. JSTL will make the `forEach` tag available which can be used to iterate over you collection.

*make sure your objects follow the bean naming convention*

```
<c:forEach items="${dc1.metrics}" var="m">
    <tr>
        <td>${m.machineName}</td>
        <td>${m.t2_95}</td>
        <td>${m.t2_99}</td>
        <td>${m.syncs}</td>
        <td>${m.syncsBehind}</td>
        <td>${m.average}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thanks Bart.. Then how my controller method will look like? I guess something has to be change there as well? Because I would like to pass `mappings` object to JSP page and then iterate that in JSP using JSTL. As I need to show which datacenter metrics is this.. As the above metrics is for `datacenter1`..

Comment: Put `model.put("dc1", mappings)` before your `return` statement. I will adjust the example accordingly.

Comment: In the `mappings` object itself, I have a string `datacenter` which will define whether this object is for `datacenter1` or `datacenter2`. If I do it like this `model.put("dc1", mappings)` then how will it work for `dc2`? My ultimate goal is to have one table for one datacenter which is `dc1` and other table for second datacenter which is `dc2`.. And currently I have three datacenters.. so max it will be three tables..

Comment: You can also create a collection of mappings. The concept must be clear now so you can apply it as you please.